# Serializing datatable throws strange exception

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I want to serialize a `Datatable`, containing several other datatables. In the past, I never had problems with this code:

```
System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(fName, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew);
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file);
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

try{
    bf.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, dt);
}catch(System.Exception ex){throw new System.Exception("Error serializing data stack!" + System.Environment.NewLine + "Error details: " + ex.Message);}

writer.Close();
writer.Dispose();

file.Close();
file.Dispose();
```

But this time, I get an exception with a strange text (sorry - just got it in German language):

> Error serializing data stack!
>   Error details: Das Ersatzzeichenpaar (0xDB8C, 0xAD3) ist ungültig. Ein hohes Ersatzzeichen (0xD800 - 0xDBFF) muss stets mit einem niedrigen Ersatzzeichen (0xDC00 - 0xDFFF) ein Paar bilden.`

You can translate that with:

> The substitute character (0xDB8C, 0xAD3) is invalid. A high substitute character always has to be paired with a low substitute character (0xDC00 - 0xDFFF).`

I really have no idea what that could mean using a binare formatter.

Comment: A DataTable doesn't contain other datatables. *Datasets* do. Datasets and DataTables can be serialized to XML directly. BinaryFormatter is *not* used in general and considered a security risk too. As for the error, post the *actual* exception text, not just the message. The full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()` contains the type of the exception, any inner exceptions and the call stack. A translated message is ungooglable while the exception type and call stack can point to the error immediatelly, or be used to google for it

Comment: As a side note. Handling exceptions in that way is not correct. You are loosing the stack trace just to add your own message to the poor end user, that surely doesn't understand what are you writing there. Better log the error in a file or database and just give a friendly error message

Comment: Looks like BinaryFormatter can't handle [unpaired surrogates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.7.2#unpaired-surrogates). Another reason *not* to use it

Comment: @Jan021981 what are you trying to do, and why are you using BinaryFormatter? Why nod XML? I suspect a zipped XML file will be smaller than anything the BinaryFormatter produces, without the quirks and security risks

Comment: A DataTable can contain other DataTables: `DataTable.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("My subtalbes", typeof(DataTable)));` Im working here with the Software `BluePrism` which is .Net based and this programm only provides Datatable. I cannot use other containers.

Comment: Ok, to be honest, the BinaryFormatter always worked for me. But I'll try your way, after I found out, how. Thank you.

Comment: @Jan021981 no, a datatable can't contain other datatables. A Datatable can have a relation to other data tables in the same dataset. Just because a column can have an arbitrary type doesn't mean this is going to work well. I suspect you used BinaryFormatter until now because other serializers choked when they found a DataTable-typed column. That's something that can't be serialized to XML, can't be mapped to/from SQL queries using adapters

Comment: @Jan021981 as for BluePrism, if it works with DataTable it works with XML too. That's because DataSets, DataTables and XmlDocument were built to complement each other. You can load/save a DataTable or Dataset from/to XML directly

Answer (score 0):

One of the records in the data table has an invalid Unicode character in a text field.  Try to isolate it by filtering out records one by one.

In a loop, create a new data table with only one record, for every record in the data table.  Try to serialize the single-record DT.  See on which record it will fail.  Then examine the record and see what is wrong.